# GDALDriver::Create GTiff Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdal

I am new to using GDAL, and am having trouble creating a GDALDataset using the GDALDriver::Create() method. In this case, I am using C++. Ultimately I am trying to create a raster and write values from an array to the raster. A minimal working example of the code that generates the problem of creating a dataset is given here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include </usr/include/gdal/gdal_priv.h>

int main(){
  std::cout << "starting GDAL business\n";
  const char *raster_format = "GTiff"; 
  GDALDriver *g_driver; 
  g_driver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(raster_format);
  GDALDataset *g_dataset;
  const char *test_file = "test_file.tif";
  char **raster_creation_options = NULL;
  std::cout << "raster options created\n";
  g_dataset = g_driver->Create(test_file,
                               100,200,1,GDT_Float32,
                               raster_creation_options); //<--- seg faults
  std::cout << "dataset created\n";
}
```

The resulting console looks like:

```
starting GDAL business
raster options created
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am just following the basic API tutorial ([Link](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html)), but am encountering this problem. I am on Ubuntu 14.04, using the repository's libgdal packages.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Are you checking your return values, e.g. are you sure `g_driver` is valid and not null?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It was indeed a case where g_driver was NULL, indicating that the GTiff driver could not be loaded. It seems like this is a known problem (http://adventuresindevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/04/compile-gdal-with-geotiff-support.html), and I used the directions at this site to compile from source with geotiff support (there was an error in the configure option (-with-libtif should be -with-libtiff). Still having the same problem with the GTiff driver not loading....

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and the issue has probably long since been resolved, but I figured I would throw my answer into the ring.  After all, I was directed here when I had this problem and it seems like the question has a fair amount of views.

If your code is not working, and you are having trouble loading the driver, I would suggest adding the line `GDALAllRegister();`.  I was following the same tutorial as you, and they mention adding this line at the top of the tutorial, but if you're like my and rushed right to the part you needed, the Create part of the tutorial, you probably overlooked that step.

Hopefully this answer helps someone, if not the original author of the question.